# Document picker view is showing inverse ? (iOS XR model onwards)

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I hit with a weired issue which I haven't seen before... In my app, there is an option to upload the document from the files.. After clicking the upload documents multiple times,, sometimes its showing inverse view,, My app is supported by arabic language and inside there is an option to change the language to arabic,, I have explicitly set the 'semanticContentAttribute', but still issue not fixed..?

Thanks in Advance

```
 documentPicker.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove :

```
modalPresentationStyle
```

Use Only :

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
importMenu.delegate = self
self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Comment: Could you please add some more info about why this is going to fix the issue.